# JSON response parsing sometimes array sometimes text

Tags: arrays, json, rest, groovy, jmeter

I have two services: register and search, with identical responses:

```
{
   "STDCode": "022",
   "Name": "MyName",
   "mobileNumber": 9876543210,
   "otherPhoneNumbers": [
      1111111111,
      2222222222,
      3333333333
   ],
   "language": "EN",
   "gender": "M",
   "Address": "......"
}
```

Although the responses are identical the assertions passing in JMeter are a bit different for both.

I am using the jsonSlurper to parse the result as

```
import groovy.json.*
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
```

The assertions I use successfully are

```
assert result.Name == "MyName"
// Successful with register fails with search
assert result.Name[0] == "MyName"
// Successful with search fails with register
```

Just wanted to know why I have to use array structure sometime and sometimes assertion works without array structure [0]? Is it something I am missing while using the parsing function or just the way the dev has coded the service ?

Comment: Most likely you have `[{"Name": "MyName"}]` in one and `{"Name": "MyName"}` in the other.  The `[0]` will then get "delayed" down to the `Name` (e.g. `result.farmerProfile[0].Name` would result in the same). AKA: the responses are **not** the same.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same response?  Not `"Name":["MyName"]` in search?

Answer (score 2):

Your two responses are **not** the same.  There is a minor difference.  Along in your path of `result.farmerProfile.Name` is a list.  E.g. (note the `[{...}]` there):

```
import groovy.json.*
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('''\
[{
   "STDCode": "022",
   "Name": "MyName",
   "mobileNumber": 9876543210,
   "otherPhoneNumbers": [
      1111111111,
      2222222222,
      3333333333
   ],
   "language": "EN",
   "gender": "M",
   "Address": "......"
}]''')

println result.Name // [MyName]
println result.Name[0] // MyName
println result*.Name // [MyName]
println result*.Name[0] // MyName
```

The reason is the implicit spread operator (note the `*.Name`). So you have most likely a list of `farmerProfile` in one and the object itself in the other.  Which makes sense, since a search would be able to return more than one I guess.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is the difference in the response that is causing difference in assertions. Actually it is a business requirement that the responses to the two REST API requests register and search should be the same. So a bit confused on whether this should be a bug between the two services or not ?

Comment: @SuhasDeshpande to really be sure, you have to investigate the two results carefully.  From a groovy/json standpoint, there is no other explanation (or at least i don't see one). Next things would be investigate if at some point you loading the JSON something goes wrong (e.g. fetch the results with curl).

Comment: Looks like your test has worked and you have a bug in your endpoints

Comment: Just another question about "implicit spread operator"
For a JSON structure as described below
{
    "Type": "Customers",
    "Details": [
        {
            "Name": "SomeName",
            "phone": "11111"
        },
        {
            "Name": "AnotherName",
            "phone": "22222"
        }
    ]
}
Will the following assertion pass or fail ?
    assert result.Details*.Name == AnotherName